# Stuck While Installing Ubuntu along side Windows 10

Tags: 16.04

I'm a windows user and I wanna learn linux so to get a feel of the OS I tried to install Ubuntu along my windows 10. Now this windows 10 wasn't pre-installed. When I try to boot using an USB I get the first orange+purplish screen with the human and keyboard icon And then I get a black screen with an underscore blinking this is where I'm stuck at. I did some research and hitting enter on that purplish screen and using nomodest alone and with some other settings didn't solve the problem.
My windows 10  is installed in legacy mode, And If I try to boot in UEFI mode It doesn't even detect any OS om my HDD. And if I use the same bootable USB drive in UEFI mode I'm stuck at the same place. Is this because I'm using windows 10 in Legacy mode and I should re-install it in UEFI mode?
Please Help me with this installation.

System Details :
Acer Aspire E5 573G laptop
i3 gen5 processor with 8 gb ddr3 ram
Nvidia GrForce 920M.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) about UEFI on the official Ubuntu documentation that covers the subject matter pretty well.

The gist of it is that if you have an OS (like Windows) in legacy mode, you'll have to have the other OS (Linux) in legacy mode too, that is likely why Ubuntu is being skipped on your machine when you turn UEFI on.

Also make sure that you downloaded a 64 bit image of Ubuntu, since the 32 bit version doesn't support UEFI at all. If you read the link to the guide I gave you carefully it'll all make sense.

From my experience, I'd suggest you to install Windows 10 in UEFI mode, then follow the guide on how to install Ubuntu and once the dual booth mode is working perfectly install your video card drivers or third party software that requires you to disable secure boot via the MOK management utility.

When (and if) you'll decide to install third party drivers (you can do that in the Ubuntu installation itself) you'll be asked to input a password to disable secure boot at the next reboot. When the system will reboot The MOK management utility will show up, it's similar to GRUB in style, very monochromatic.

It'll have four options: 
continue booting, disable secure boot, enroll hash (was it?), enroll (can't remember). I really can't remember the last two but they're not important in this context.

You'll have to choose the second option (secure boot) and insert the password by entering the correct character(s) it will ask you pertaining to the password you entered before. If you don't choose the second option and boot normally the MOK management utility won't start again unless you uninstall and install third-party drivers again. So be careful. There is likely a way to invoke it by using some arcane command, maybe someone more experienced can enlighten us.

Comment: I tried to install windows 10 in UEFI mode but it doesn't detect any bootable media not even my bootable pendrive which it detects  when I load it in Legacy mode. Any thoughts? I'm all lost.

Comment: Have you tried disabling _fast startup_ or _fast boot_ in your BIOS also?
Disable (if it's there) also the  _Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT)_ always in the BIOS.
You'll even have to disable _fast startup_ in Windows itself, by going to Settings > Power Management and unchecking the option, yep it's in the power management settings. What happens is that the main NTFS OS headers will be overwritten to boot Windows faster and will lock your main drive making it read only or not accessible at all.
Also try changing the USB port you plug it into before booting.
(Remeber partitioning also)

Comment: Didn't work buddy. It still wont detect anything. Why can't I install ubuntu in legacy mode??

Comment: Did you put your USB drive first in the boot order priority in the BIOS? You might want to try also another USB pendrive, some just don't work. 
For instance a 4GB SandDisk Cruzer Blade always worked for me.

Comment: Yup tried everything it just wont load.

Comment: At this point I believe it's got something to do with your vendor BIOS specifically, you might want to try to contact them directly. Good luck.